# How to construct the unity partition on $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

How to construct the unity partition on $\mathbb{S}^1$?

I was reading the construction of unity partition on $\mathbb{S}^1$ given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity. I would like to understand the steps please.

First, I know that $\mathbb{S}^1=\left \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2=1\right \}$ and I need to find two functions $\psi _i:\mathbb{S}^1\to [0,1]$, $i=1,2$ and for every $p\in \mathbb{S}^1$ we need that $\psi _1(p)+\psi _2(p)=1$. Wikipedia used the function $\Phi (t)=e^\frac{1}{t^2-1}$, for $t\in (-1,1)$. Now i want to connect that function with the functions $\psi _i$. They choose $\psi _1=\Phi$ and $\psi _2=1-\Phi$, but I do not understand why it works since the domain of $\psi _i$ need to be $\mathbb{S}^1$ instead of $(-1,1)$. Can somebody help me to understand what is the idea behind of this or I do not get it?  Thank you.

Comment: The description in the Wikipedia article isn't very good, but they are defining the function using charts on $S^1$ (so they can represent functions on the charts by functions on $\Bbb{R}$). The description isn't very good, because they should say that they are giving a partition of unity that is subordinate to the open cover given by two sets $S^1 \setminus\{p\}$ and $S^1 \setminus\{q\}$ for two points $p$ and $q$ of $S^1$ and their definition of a partition of unity talks about total functions on $X$ rather than functions on open subsets of $X$.

Comment: @RobArthan  thank you for the comment. Please can you tell me something about the functions $\psi_i$. What is the relation with the other function $\phi$ please!!?

Comment: BTW, if you're interested in finding two such functions, you could use $\psi_1=\cos^2$ and $\psi_2=\sin^2$ :-)

Comment: @StefanLafon or just identical 1?

Comment: Yep, that works too! I just wanted something slightly less of a degenerate case :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi: S^1\setminus\{p\} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the stereographic projection. Let $\Phi$ be the $\Phi$ from above. Set $\psi_1(x) := \Phi \circ\varphi(x)$ for $x \in S^1\setminus\{p\}$ and $\psi_1(p) := 0$. Then $\psi_1$ is a continuous function on $S^1$ with support in $S^1\setminus \{p\}$, because $\text{supp} \ \Phi \circ \varphi \subseteq S^1\setminus\{p\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for anybody. Best

Comment: For me $\psi_1(x,y)= e^{\frac{(1-y)^2}{x^2 -(1-y)^2}}$. I am not sure if i did well?  Thank you